# Modified height-balanced tree algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I need to find if a binary tree is height-balanced but instead of considering the paths from root to leaf I need to consider the paths from root to a node that has either left or right child null.

This is the logic of my algorithm in pseudo-code:

```
bool isBalanced=true //to know if the tree is balanced or not a flag is used
void findBalance(root,currentDepth,shortestPathDepth){
   if(root==null){
       return;
   }
   if(root->left_child=null or root->right_child=null) //if the last node of a path has been found

       if(shortestPathDepth=-1)          //if this is the first end of a path that has been found                             
         shortestPathDepth=currentDepth  //it will be used as comparison value for all the other paths

       else //if the end of a path was already found before
          if(currentDepth>shortestPathDepth+1) // if the condition of height-balance is not fulfilled
            isBalanced=false;
            return;
   //traverse the rest of the nodes keeping track of the depth of the nodes and the value of the path that 
   //will be used for the condition
   findBalance(root->left,currentDepth+1,shortestPathDepth);
   findBalance(root->right,currentDepth+1,shortestPathDepth);
```

I'm looking for help to understand  what is wrong with this logic.

Edit

The real code:

```
void findBalance(Node node,int currentDepth,int* pathDepth,int* flag){
    if(node==nullptr || *flag==0){
        return;
    }
    if(node->left==nullptr || node->right==nullptr){
        if(*pathDepth==-1){
            *pathDepth=currentDepth;
        }
        else{
            if(currentDepth>pathDepth+1){
                 *flag=0;
            }  
        } 
    }
    findBalance(node->left,currentDepth+1,pathDepth,flag);
    findBalance(node->right,currentDepth+1,pathDepth,flag);
}

bool isBalanced(Node root){
    if(root==nullptr){
        return true;
    }
    int flag=1;
    int pathDepth=-1;
    findBalance(u,0,&pathDepth,&flag);
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: One thing I notice is in the second `if` statement you have `=` in two places where you probably meant `==`.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, this is just pseudo-code with the logic but the original code compiles

Comment: Please provide the original code then. This code is too ambiguous. For instance you sometimes use braces around statement blocks, but not always. Since you have a problem with real code, provide real code.

Comment: Also explain how that definition of "balanced" works: can you provide non-trivial examples of balanced trees and non-balanced trees, based on this special definition?

Comment: @trincot I added the real code. For the definition: for path it is intended any path that starts from the root and ends with a node that is either missing the left child or the right child, the length of each path of this kind in the binary tree can't differ of more than 1. So for example if there are two paths of that kind, if one is made of 3 nodes and the other of 5 nodes, then the tree is not balance because the difference is 2.

Comment: can you provide non-trivial examples of balanced trees and non-balanced trees, based on this special definition?

Comment: @trincot for example, a tree in which the difference between the length of the longest path from root to leaf and the the value of currentDepth of a node that has either left or right child null is always <2, is balanced and the opposite not.

Comment: @trincot to be more clear, if the condition in else was  if (abs(currentDepth-longestRootToLeafPath(Node node)<2) then the program works as intended, the problem is that to find the length of the longest path from root to leaf I needed to use an extra function longestRootToLeafPath that makes the complexity of the solution worse because it makes me traverse the tree more than once. So I had to chance my solution to make the complexity better and is not working anymore as intended.

Comment: I don't see how the "real code" could compile: `pathDepth` is not an integer (which may well be your problem), `u` is undeclared.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add examples (positive and negative). Images would help.